# PHP: I need a database-like solution which stores data in local filesystem

Tags: php, database, flat-file

It's a rather long story but to make it short I need to store a part of my database locally, in the filesystem. I can't use normal database like MySQL and I can't use XML files (theoretically I can use XML-s but they are not flexible enough, I will need some very complex layer of PHP code to make XML-s usable). Is there some kind of solution which will allow to move several DB tables to filesystem and do normal operations with them?

I worked with flat files years ago and they are very close to what I need. However what I didn't like about flat files is that they are crude - you need to do everything manually, you can't just do something like "SELECT name FROM some_table WHERE age>30", instead you need to manually go through file and select the required entries.

So, could you suggest some solution that imitates SQL but stores everything in a local file. Also this shouldn't be something very exotic because the product will be deployed on many random hostings and usually we don't have control over what is installed there.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not try SQLite? It sounds like what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is called SQLite: http://www.sqlite.org/ It's well supported within PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Answer (score 1):

[Gladius DB](http://gladius.sourceforge.net/) is a fast and efficient PHP flatfile database engine written in pure PHP; its SQL syntax is compatible with a subset of intermediate SQL92. You will not need any specific extension to have it work, and it is bundled with an adoDB lite driver.